# C++ and Enum and class members

Tags: c++, windows

Following code is not compiling, can anybody please help what is wrong here

```
class CTrapInfo
{
public:
    enum GenericType
    {
        ColdStart,    
        WarmStart,
        LinkDown,    
        LinkUp,
        AuthenticationFailure,    
        EGPNeighborLoss,
        EnterpriseSpecific
    };
    CTrapInfo();
    CTrapInfo(const CTrapInfo&);
    ~CTrapInfo();   
    CTrapInfo &operator=(const CTrapInfo&);
    static GenericType toGenericType(const DOMString&);
};
```

Compiler error is :

> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed.

Note: C++ does not support default-int
MSDN says this is valid in c++ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Have you tried without "CAPTrapInfo::" ? Aren't you missing ";" at the end of the class definition ?

Comment: Sorry it was mistake during posting a question, 
I have tried without ::also.

Comment: well your `operator=` has `CTrapInfo` spelled wrong

Comment: What line does the error refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It compiles for me, in VS2005, if I forward declare class CAPTrapInfo and class DOMSTring.

Comment: @Avinash: it's a little hard to follow this question-page, so please select this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure CAPTrapInfo and DOMString are defined? If they are not defined you will get the error.

Comment: That was a typo and DOMstring is included in my header file

Answer (score 0):

For which line does the compiler indicate the error? It could be that you did not include a definition for `DOMString`, so that the compiler might assume `int` in `toGenericType(const DOMString&)`.